# Bootstrap datetimepicker :: how can i set it in 'hh:mm:ss' format?

Tags: datetimepicker, timepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How can I set a particular format in bootstrap 3 [Datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)?. The format should be "hh:mm:ss" and I don't want "AM" and "PM". Actually, this is for selecting Hours, minutes and seconds. I tried with this code,but it is not working.

```
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker4' />
       </div>

       <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
              pickDate: false
        });
       </script>
     </div>
   </div>
```

I want to get it to appear like this -

[image: demo date picker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [format](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#format) option to set the date format you prefer. In your case you can have:

```
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format: 'HH:mm:ss'
});
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: But I had to include the momentjs.

Comment: As you can see from ["Installing" section](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/), you need to include momentjs to make bootstrap-datetimepicker work properly.